# postfix wildcard for subdomains

Tags: postfix, subdomain, wildcards

I have a hash:/exclude.file in main.cf which checks for ips/domains to exclude them from rbl checks.
The exclude.file contains something like:
 `foo.com      PERMIT`
 `xx.yy.zz.ff   PERMIT`
but it does not catch foo.com's subdomains. It only works for IPs. I need something like:
`*.foo.com    PERMIT`
Any way to use wildcards in there?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are using the `check_client_access` directive in `smtpd_client_restrictions` or maybe `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

The correct usage would be:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
    ... maybe permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated etc...
    reject_unauth_destination,
    ... more checks ...
    check_client_access hash:/path/to/file,
    ... RBL etc...
```

It is important to `reject_unaith_destination` before checking client access, because if the `check_client_access` lookup returns `PERMIT`, you will be an open relay.

Then, so enable wildcard lookups on hostnames, use:

```
.domain.tld  PERMIT
```

Comment: `NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from nm30-vm1.bullet.mail.ac4.yahoo.com[98.139.52.251]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [98.139.52.251] blocked using safe.dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam` although I have added `.yahoo.com PERMIT`. Yes, your guess is correct: `smtpd_client_restrictions -> permit_mynetworks -> reject_unknown_recipient_domain -> reject_unauth_destination -> check_client_access hash:/exclude.file -> reject_rbl_client safe.dnsbl.sorbs.net`